# MySQL - group by is possible only with "filesort" and "using temporary"?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way how to use group by in MySQL without "filesort" and "using temporary"? Tried different indexes, different broup by, different order by but always the same result - "using filesort" or "using filesort + using temporary".

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ank1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `kmk` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `order_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `gender` (`gender`,`kmk`,`uid`,`order_by`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


mysql> explain SELECT gender, kmk, order_by FROM ank1
    -> where
    -> gender IN (1, 2, 3) and
    -> kmk IN (1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 23, 123)
    -> group by uid
    -> order by order_by DESC limit 0, 30;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ank1  | index | gender        | gender | 13      | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Even group by and order by the same column gives the same rusults:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ank1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `kmk` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `order_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `gender` (`gender`,`kmk`,`order_by`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

mysql> explain SELECT gender, kmk, order_by FROM ank1
    -> where
    -> gender IN (1, 2, 3) and
    -> kmk IN (1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 23, 123)
    -> group by order_by
    -> order by order_by DESC limit 0, 30;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ank1  | index | gender        | gender | 9       | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is malformed because it uses a (mis)feature of MySQL that permits columns in the SQL that are not in the `group by`.  There is probably no way around the file sort when using this (mis)feature.

Comment: I tried without group by in the select statement but the result is the same.